# EmitterProcessor is deprecated. How to replace it?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a class.

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class ResourceRest {

   private final EmitterProcessor<String> streamProcessor = EmitterProcessor.create();

    @GetMapping(value = "/sse", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> getSee() {
        return this.streamProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Flux<String>> receiveSse() {

        return recordFlux ->
                recordFlux
                        .doOnNext(this.streamProcessor::onNext)
                        .doOnNext(value -> log.info("*" +value))
                        .subscribe();
    }
}
```

I found out that it can be replaced like this

```java
Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
```

The data must be obtained from RabbitMQ. The project uses Spring Cloud Stream.

First, the data is published by the producer-service in Rabbit. Then the processor-service processes them, wraps them in a container (AccumulatorMessage) and publishes them to another RabbitMQ queue, from where the data is taken by the consumer-service.

```java
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.cloud.stream.function.definition}")
    private String definition;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<AccumulatorMessage> receive() {

        return payload -> {
            log.info(payload.toString());
        };
    }
}
```

- application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5673
    username: guest
    password: guest
  application:
    name: consumer-service


  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
             definition: receive; receiveSse
      bindings:
        receive-in-0:
          destination: accumulatorMessageChannel
          group: accumulatorMessageChannelGroup
        receiveSse-in-0:
          destination: accumulatorMessageChannel
          group: accumulatorMessageChannelGroup

server:
  port: 8030
```

The method **receiveSse()** is added as a **binding**.

But how can I apply this to that class and how does it work at all ?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: It doesn't that.